# pyauto gui TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pyautogui

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui, time, random
time.sleep(5)
integer = random.randint(1, 1000)
while True:
    pyautogui.typewrite(integer)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.sleep(10)
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am basically trying to print a random integer. Could somebody please help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: When posting error messages, include the full traceback so we can see which line raised the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `typewrite()` is expecting a string. Try `pyautogui.typewrite(str(integer))` instead.

> This works. Thank you so much. I have one problem -- It is printing the exact same number every time (110).

If you re-run the program then it should be a different number. If you want a new number every loop, then you should put the `integer = random.randint(1, 1000)` line inside the loop to be repeated instead of just doing it once before looping.

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. I have one problem -- It is printing the exact same number every time (110). Please help me with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much.